# Xamarin / SQLite: update doubles in a database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app that will store a list of receipes for some chemicals.  The chemicals have names (not user changeable) and concentrations.  I want the user to be able to change the concentrations in the form and store them.

I have it to where I can modify values in the list with the UPDATE button, I can add (or delete) members of the list, all persistent.  However, I cannot figure out how to change the values in the list within the Entry box, itself.

I tried to do something like [Arvind Chourasiya did here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906245/how-to-update-specific-data-into-sqlite-in-xamarin), but I could not quite figure out the equivalent "connection.Update."  I think the SQLite can't be connected to because it's not in the right event, but I am not sure.

My most functional C# code is...

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SQLite;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace contactBook
{

    public class Recipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        private string _name;

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Name
        { 
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name == value)
                    return;

                _name = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double _concentration;

        public double Concentration
        {
            get
            { return _concentration; }
            set
            {
                if (_concentration == value)
                    return;

                _concentration = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
        private ObservableCollection<Recipe> _recipes;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
            //setBasicReceipies();

        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        { 
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Recipe>();

            var recipes = await _connection.Table<Recipe>().ToListAsync();
            _recipes = new ObservableCollection<Recipe>(recipes);
            recipesListView.ItemsSource = _recipes;

            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        async void setBasicReceipies()  // worked during tests
        {

            var recipe1 = new Recipe { Name = "NH3", Concentration = 0.0 };
            var recipe2 = new Recipe { Name = "H2SO4", Concentration = 0.1 };
            var recipe3 = new Recipe { Name = "NaCl", Concentration = 0.2 };

            await _connection.InsertAsync(recipe1);
            await _connection.InsertAsync(recipe2);
            await _connection.InsertAsync(recipe3);
        }

        async void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var recipe = new Recipe { Name = "test ", Concentration = 0.0 };
            await _connection.InsertAsync(recipe);

            _recipes.Add(recipe);
        }

        async void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var recipe = _recipes[0];
            recipe.Concentration += 0.05;

            await _connection.UpdateAsync(recipe);
        }

        async void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var recipe = _recipes[0];
            await _connection.DeleteAsync(recipe);
            _recipes.Remove(recipe);
        }

        //async void Entry_PropertyChanged(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    await _connection.UpdateAllAsync();
        //}

    }
}
```

Comment: "I cannot figure out how to change the values in the list within the Entry box" - I have no idea what this means.  What Entry box?  Do you mean you cannot get the UI to display your new values?  Or that you cannot get the updated values from your UI to save in the DB?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Just FYI - I recently wrote this blog post that will help make some performance improvements with your SQLite database: https://codetraveler.io/2019/11/26/efficiently-initializing-sqlite-database/

Comment: I think you problem you don't know how to update value in DB when you click UPDATE button? Then you should show us more relevant codes.